# SVN import confusion

Tags: svn, command-line, import

I downloaded the SVN source, got it installed and added to my path for easy access. So far, so good.

```
svn --version
svn, version 1.6.6 (r40053)
   compiled Oct 22 2009, 14:13:09
```

Reading the documentation (that everyone will want to point me to anyway), it instructs me to create a project:

```
svnadmin create tdl
```

Then, to add an unversioned copy of code, execute

```
svn import tdl file:///Users/webdev/Documents/dev/svn/tdl
```

What occurred next stumped me. I get an emacs terminal that looks like this:
[screencap http://files.me.com/mjstelly/1ke13o](http://files.me.com/mjstelly/1ke13o)

I have no idea what to make of this. I thought I did something wrong. So I closed the terminal and tried again. Same thing.

Has anyone experienced this before? If so, what the heck am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shortly after everyone responded (ty for quick reply), I found that I could run this from tdl parent directory.

svn import tdl file:///Users/webdev/Documents/dev/svn/tdl -m "initial import" 

That's what I was missing. So if I don't use the -m, then it'll prompt me. I get it now. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that emacs terminal type the message of the import, for example:

> First commit, base project structure

...then save it and the svn import will take place.

Answer (score 1):

SVN is invoking your default EDITOR (which for you, appears to be emacs) so you can write the commit log message.  You can stop this by using the "-m" option to specify the commit message on the "svn import" command line.

Answer (score 0):

It's asking for a comment from you regarding this import. NOrmally people just write "Initial commit" and then out from the text editor.

Answer (score 0):

It wants you to write a log entry for this commit.  Something like "Importing the project".  It'll do this for every commit.